# swift tableview to webview

Tags: ios, uitableview, webview, xcode6

I have a problem with table view, select a cell that sends me to a web view, but not at the code, I am new to developing applications ios. thanx

```
var arr: [String]?
    var index : Int = Int()

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    arr = ["google","yahoo","Swift"]
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
}


override func numberOfSectionsInTableView(tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
            return 1
        }

    override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return arr!.count
    }

    override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

        //var identifier : NSString = "Cell"

        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("Cell", forIndexPath: indexPath ) as UITableViewCell
```

the problem this is in line

```
override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
            return arr!.count
        }
```

This is the console message:

> tableView  UITableView 0x00007fc504033a00  0x00007fc504033a00 section  Int 0   0 self OtraPrueba.ViewController    0x00007fc503548ca0  0x00007fc503548ca0 UIKit.UITableViewController  UITableViewController   0x0000000105a4b3d0  0x000000010‌​5a4b3d0 arr    [String]?   3 values    Some [0]    String  "google"    [1] String  "yahoo" [2] String  "Swift" index   Int 0   0

Comment: What is the error you are getting?

Comment: `tableView UITableView 0x00007fc504033a00 0x00007fc504033a00
section Int 0 0
self OtraPrueba.ViewController 0x00007fc503548ca0 0x00007fc503548ca0
UIKit.UITableViewController UITableViewController 0x0000000105a4b3d0 0x0000000105a4b3d0
arr [String]? 3 values Some
[0] String "google" 
[1] String "yahoo" 
[2] String "Swift" 
index Int 0 0 `

Comment: This looks like printed description of your variables. Is your program crashing on running?

Comment: running but after crashing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you sure its crashing?
Your console shows description of variables and no error messages.
You have put breakpoint in your code and it may not be crashing. Try running after removing (or disabling) the break points.

Comment: Ohhh My Godd!! jaja Sorry for my question nob, yes running!! thankz